# parallel port programming

Tags: vb6, hardware, parallel-port

Quick question: Can a parallel port receive and send data at same time?

And if you have more tips about VB and parallel port programming, please feel free to tell me. :)

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can send and receive at the same time.

Try this page for using VB  http://www.aaroncake.net/electronics/vblpt.htm

And a good page on parallel ports http://www.lvr.com/parport.htm

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you develop it more how it would work in practice? with a exmepl, I would be very grateful.

Comment: I don't know VB, so the quick answer is no I can't help.  I do know parallel ports and they have separate input and output lines, which means that they can send and receive simultaneously.  More info: http://www.lvr.com/parport.htm  might help.